# MySQL: How to find a value that may exist across multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I currently have a table that stores rankings of music sales in a shop:

```
|-date-------|-rank_1---|-rank_2---|-...
| 2015-06-30 | 112      | 145      | ...
| 2015-07-31 | 145      | 147      | ...
| ...
| ...
```

Each number in the *rank_#* column is a foreign key that references an album in a separate table:

```
|-album_id---|-album_name----|-...
| 112        | An Album      | ...
| 145        | Another Album | ...
| ...
```

I want to implement a feature where I can search for an album and see its ranking across the dates. However, the *album_id* can show up in any of the *rank_#* columns and I'd like to know if there was any way that I could "invert" the tables so I get a result like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ....

=> |-date-------|-column-----|
   | 2015-06-30 | rank_2     |
   | 2015-07-31 | rank_1     |
   | ...
```

Now, the brute-force method I can think of is just to loop through the table and look at each cell in the table, but seeing as how the table is quite large, I was wondering if there was a more efficient method of doing this.

Comment: I should also add that the same *album_id* does not show up twice in one row (for a specific date) since a single album can't occupy more than one sales ranking.

Comment: Fix your data structure to have one row per date and per album, with its ranking.  Make the data structure more SQLish and the query will be much easier.

Comment: Are you on sqlite or mysql? You tagged both?

Comment: @trincot MySQL. Sorry about accidentally tagging SQLite.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the table current is set up so that its: date | rank_1 | rank_2 ... with no date showing up twice. I guess I'm not understanding what you mean by "one row per date and per album."

Comment: He means set up the table so it has columns "date", "album", and "rank". You'll have multiple entries for each date. So right now you've got up until "rank_5", what happens when you want to store your top 10? You have to rebuild your database.

Comment: @miken32 I see. Is this method recommended if the ranking were to go to into the (low) hundreds per date? (like 150 rankings per date). I'd end up with a table with tens of thousands of rows since I have like a decade's worth of data.

Comment: @WolframRong - I have a ranking database for something similar (not music) to you - hundreds of thousands of rows (adding hundreds of new rows every week) going back into the late 1990's - but the queries are fast - and works. They are right. You need to normalize.

Comment: It's not really a method, just [how things are done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). And it is recommended if you have 2 rankings per date or 200. Doesn't matter how many you have, fitting your data into numbered columns is never a good idea. And 10000 rows is nothing! Why would you worry about number of rows and not number of columns?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone! It seems like I was structuring the tables incorrectly and instead should have set it up like:

```
|-date-------|-album_id-|-rank--|
| 2015-06-30 | 112      | 1     |
| 2015-07-31 | 145      | 2     |
| ...
| ...
```

Comment: If you want some data integrity protection, you can put unique keys on (date, album_id) and/or (date, rank) to insure an album can't be on the same date twice and/or two albums can't have the same rank on the same date...though this observation reveals another flaw with your original design, you wouldn't have been able to represent a tie in your data.

Comment: Also, just thought I would throw out there that (1) you may want to rename the `date` column to something that doesn't collide with a data type name, and (2) make sure your date field is a date/datetime/timestamp type; problems stemming from using strings to store such info are quite frequently seen around here.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfgang, here's my approach:

***Albums Table:***

```
album_id;album_name
1;ska
2;psychobilly
3;punk
4;nu-metal
```

***Rankings Table:***

```
id;date;rank_1;rank_2
1;2016-08-01;1;2
2;2016-08-02;2;1
4;2016-08-03;2;4
```

***Suggested Query:***

```
select r.date,a.album_id,a.album_name,r.rank_1,r.rank_2,  
case 
    when a.album_id= r.rank_1 then "rank_1"
    when a.album_id= r.rank_2 then "rank_2"
end as "rank"
from albums a 
inner join rankings r on (r.rank_1=a.album_id or r.rank_2=a.album_id)
where a.album_name like '%psychobilly%'
```

***Results:***

```
date;album_id;album_name;rank_1;rank_2;rank
2016-08-01;2;psychobilly;1;2;rank_2
2016-08-02;2;psychobilly;2;1;rank_1
2016-08-03;2;psychobilly;2;4;rank_1
```

***Explanation:***

The last column of the query will contain the position in the ranking, according to the value of the album id, between "rank_1" and "rank_2" columns.

Feel free to try, this may help you...